# How do I package ASP.Net User Controls (ascx) into a DLL for sharing across projects?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ascx

I'm working on an straight ASP.Net application. (no additional frameworks).

I've got several user controls (not custom controls) which I'd like to be able to package into a DLL for reuse/redistribution across several other applications. Ideally, we'd like to have everything self contained in (.ascx and source files) a DLL which could be added to the target project's references.

When embedding the user controls into .aspx pages, we'd like to be able see those controls in Visual Studio design view.

I've been looking around and seen several possible solutions for this.
Can anyone point me to a clear tutorial/example which will help step me through this process?

Comment: In general, that's not how user controls work. The .ascx file has to be available at runtime. You should create custom controls instead if you want to distribute in a DLL. Alternatively, you can use your source control system to "share" the files across projects.

Answer (score 0):

John, as far as I am aware, what you are asking is not possible, at least not out of the box with the .net Framework. When you build a UserControl in ASP .NET app and compile the solution, as you may have realized, the UserControl would be included in the dll of the project to which it belongs; it won't have a separate dll of its own. Since the UserControl won't have a dll of its own, you won't be able to make it available in the design view/toolbox.

For what you are asking, you might want to consider creating ServerControls instead. Server controls are  harder to create than UserControl, if I recall correctly, you have to code it entirely, wont have designer available, but when you are done and compile, ServerControl will have it's own dll, which could be made available in CustomControls under Toolbox.

If you want a starting point for ServerControl, I would highly recommend watching the video from KudVenkat. His explanation and demos are second to none. 
[Link to the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZkc-4R5lCw&index=112&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXQS_p1i-HLIftB9Y7Vnxlo)